# Truffle script: Not showing the current balance of the Smart contract (SC) after Ether transfer from account[2] immediately

Tags: truffle, truffle-console

I have a Smart contract (SC1):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
contract MySC1 {
    address owner;
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function sendTo(address payable receiver, uint amount) public {
       receiver.transfer(amount);
    }
    function() external payable{
     }
}
```

I am transferring it Ether from account2 but when I check the balance it is still zero:

```
$ truffle exec ts4.js
Using network 'development'.

acc2 balance 100000000000000000000 address 0xEa719Cf8f777350c0D0B0be8cc4A90Aa95f36898
SC1 deployed 0x43ba105f5DeC27B9c4183c95971672e53EaA9a64
SC2 deployed 0xc80c3fDE077Ce7360e738BB6525A92bf7953ea51
Initial SC1: 0x43ba105f5DeC27B9c4183c95971672e53EaA9a64  balance is 0
Initial SC2: 0xc80c3fDE077Ce7360e738BB6525A92bf7953ea51  balance is 0
11 Ether from 0xEa719Cf8f777350c0D0B0be8cc4A90Aa95f36898, sc1: 0x43ba105f5DeC27B9c4183c95971672e53EaA9a64  balance is 0
```

but when I execute the script again, it shows me the correct balance:

```
$ truffle exec ts4.js
Using network 'development'.

acc2 balance 88999579200000000000 address 0xEa719Cf8f777350c0D0B0be8cc4A90Aa95f36898
SC1 deployed 0x43ba105f5DeC27B9c4183c95971672e53EaA9a64
SC2 deployed 0xc80c3fDE077Ce7360e738BB6525A92bf7953ea51
Initial SC1: 0x43ba105f5DeC27B9c4183c95971672e53EaA9a64  balance is 11000000000000000000
Initial SC2: 0xc80c3fDE077Ce7360e738BB6525A92bf7953ea51  balance is 0
11 Ether from 0xEa719Cf8f777350c0D0B0be8cc4A90Aa95f36898, sc1: 0x43ba105f5DeC27B9c4183c95971672e53EaA9a64  balance is 11000000000000000000
```

My script is:

```
// Contracts
const  MySC1 = artifacts.require("MySC1")

module.exports = async function(callback) {
try {
    // Fetch accounts from wallet - these are unlocked
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    // Set up account to transferEther to Victim
    const acc2 = accounts[2]
    acc2bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(acc2)
    web3.utils.fromWei(acc2bal, "ether")
    console.log('acc2 balance', acc2bal, 'address',acc2)
    // Fetch the deployed exchange
    const sc1 = await MySC1.deployed()
    console.log('SC1 deployed', sc1.address)
    
    sc1bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(sc1.address)
    web3.utils.fromWei(sc1bal, "ether")
    console.log(`Initial SC1:`,sc1.address,` balance is ${sc1bal}`)
    
    amount = '11'
    web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:sc1.address, from:acc2, value: web3.utils.toWei(amount)})
    sc1bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(sc1.address)
    web3.utils.fromWei(sc1bal, "ether")
    console.log(`${amount} Ether from ${acc2}, sc1:`, sc1.address,` balance is ${sc1bal}`)
 
}
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

  callback()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try awaiting for sendTransaction?

```
await web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:sc1.address, from:acc2, value: web3.utils.toWei(amount)})
```